# <crossout>onionmx broken due to torsocks ipv6 abandonment</crossout>

Tags: torsocks, email, ipv6

Edit: Actually the torsocks v1.4.0 --ipv6 option has been working for me. See https://github.com/ehloonion/onionmx/issues/38#issuecomment-1173104130

[I've been trying][1] to get [onionmx][2] working with postfix and smtp delivery over torsocks.

It sometimes works, and sometimes randomly fails with `Resolve destination buffer too small`.

If I understand correctly there's no workaround?

See: [Ubuntu torsocks bug: "Torsocks fails to resolve domain names where ɪᴘv6 is available."](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torsocks/+bug/1975416)

And: [Tor Bug: "youtube-dl (recent), torsocks 2.1.0 and TBB5+ failure"](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/torsocks/-/issues/16934)

Setting all of the following did not help:

```
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
AddressDisableIPv6 1
NoPreferIPv6Automap (on the SocksPort)
```

Is torsocks effectively abandoned?

Comment: Actually maybe it's working now with NoPreferIPv6Automap and AddressDisableIPv6? I ran my test incorrectly last time.

Comment: Hi, your question contains several questions in one (workaround for onionmx vs. torsocks, etc.). It is better to just ask one question.

Comment: Do you have any idea or clue when the error message appears? Could you reproduce this message?